# How do I turn off Edit and Continue (for Veracode) through msbuild

Tags: c++, msbuild, veracode

I know the question does not make complete sense, as I'm not building inside of Visual Studio. I'm trying to submit my binary for a static analysis by [Veracode](http://www.veracode.com/), and I build using `msbuild`:

```
msbuild coop.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:LinkIncremental=false
```

I can turn this off in my Visual Studio environment by going to Tools > Options > Debugging > Edit and Continue, and then unchecking the 'Enabled Edit and Continue.' However, this doesn't seem to affect the solution file.

I get a warning from Veracode about having used Edit & Continue when I upload the resulting binary. I feel like there must be an option to disable that configuration through `msbuild`.

A couple of related posts that do not completely address this:

- [How to: Enable and Disable Edit and Continue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yty6a48.aspx)
- [Is there a way to *completely* disable Edit and Continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050162/is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-edit-and-continue)

Any ideas for how to disable Edit and Continue through `msbuild`?

Comment: Change /Zl to some other debug setting in the debug configuration or create an new configuration without /Zl  see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/958x11bc.aspx

Comment: Static code analyzers are not generally impressed about having to verify a debug build.  They care a lot more about the code you are going to ship to your customer.  The release build.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this. The easiest is to build your project in Release configuration. The default Release properties are setup to build with normal debug information (i.e. not an edit-and-continue).

Another solution, if you have to have a Debug binaries without edit-and-continue, you will have to modify all your projects. Add the following snippet into all your projects, somewhere close to the end of the .vcxproj file, after `Microsoft.Cpp.props` is imported:

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ClCompile>
    <DebugInformationFormat>ProgramDatabase</DebugInformationFormat>
  </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```