# how to edit code when debugging in vs code

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

I want to add a comment while debugging, but it seems to change the line numbers. Then, I added a white breakpoint instead of red.

I found a lot of answers about [visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-enable-and-disable-edit-and-continue?view=vs-2022), but it's hard to find vscode.

Is it possible to edit code while debugging in vscode?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Edit and Continue** feature to do this. This feature allows you to change your code while the debugger is paused and continue debugging without restarting the program.

[image]

To enable **Edit and Continue**, check this discussion:

[Is there a way to *completely* disable Edit and Continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050162/is-there-a-way-to-completely-disable-edit-and-continue)

Comment: linked Q&A is about VS and not VS Code?